# How to define fluid HTML layout without having to hard code absolute heights or widths for fixed content elements

Tags: html, css, layout

Could someone please advise as to the easiest way to define an HTML layout with two columns, the **first** as wide as its content requires, the **second** as wide as the remainder of the viewport, without having to actually hard code a width for either (absolute or percentage)?

#### And secondly

How would one define a layout with three rows:

- the **first** as high as it requires.
- the **second** of specified percentage height
- and the **third** as high as it requires, or the remaining height with a scroll bar if there isn't enough room

without having to actually hard code either of the two fixed heights?

Comment: The easiest way is to use HTML and CSS. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've updated the answer to fit your needs